# how to bind a string data type to dropdown list in mVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i am new to MVC5 , i created a table like Users, which has ID, title, firstname, lastname ,Manager fields.

i generated the model, view using MVC5 scaffolding. Title is a string datatype in the model, how do i bind it to dropdown having values like Mr, Mrs,Ms

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> titles = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Mr", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Mrs", Value = "2" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Ms", Value = "3" },

            };
            ViewBag.Titles = titles;

            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }


@Html.DropDownList("Titles",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Titles))
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.PersonalNo,"Value","Text"))" asp-for="@Model.DetailHoCreditCardMsts.PersonalNo" required>
     <option>---Select---</option>
</select>
```

controller

```
ViewBag.PersonalNo = EmpNameIdDesig();
```